# как получить id или тег пользователя?

Tags: aiogram

как получить id или тег пользователя нажавшего на кнопку В ГРУППЕ?
при call.message.chat.id выдает id группы при call.message.from_user.id выдает id бота

Comment: это id бота, я говорю про кнопку в группе

Comment: разные люди нажимают - один и тот же id
нажимаю я - id не мой

Answer (score 0):

Используйте call.from_user.id для получения id и call.from_user.username для тэга